# Правомерность постановки тире

Tags: стилистика, тире, запятые

«Сегодня он понимает, что и опыт далеко не гарант компетентности — особенно если это опыт выполнения одних и тех же механических обязанностей»

Может ли в данном случае, да и вообще ставиться "стилистическое" тире, когда придаточное является скорее дополнительной информацией и произносится с присоединительной интонацией?

Comment: Тире здесь нужнее после "опыта"; в другом же месте нужна запятая.

Comment: Alex_ander, здесь присоединительное придаточное предложение присоединяется словом "особенно". на месте запятой может стоять тире.

Comment: А почему вы сомневаетесь в постановке тире? В Полном академическом справочникепод редакцией Лопатина говорится следующее: Возможно выделение присоединительных членов и при помощи тире, особенно в конечной позиции: Неожиданно, перебивая ее воспоминания о ребятах, перед ней высветился дальний-дальний день — и тоже с рекой (Расп.).

Comment: И хотя об отдельном придаточном предложении там ничего не говорится, этот пункт правила можно свободно отнести и к вашему примеру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире в заданном предложении не является обязательным, оно обозначает увеличенную паузу. Однако в этом случае лучше поставить запятую и тире как единый знак:

**Сегодня он понимает, что и опыт далеко не гарант компетентности,  — особенно если это опыт выполнения одних и тех же механических обязанностей.**

Похожий пример у Розенталя.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

В смущении он говорил не то, что думал, — он произносил первые пришедшие на ум слова.

**Пояснение:**

Одно интонационное тире тоже используется, но в этом случае обычно требуются дополнительные условия (однородные придаточные, указательные слова и др.):  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Comment: Вы считате, что можно обойтись без тире после первого слова *опыт*?

Comment: Там не должно быть тире по правилам, так как между подлежащим и сказуемым находится отрицательная частица ДАЛЕКО НЕ. А в сложном предложении из трех частей даже интонационное тире неуместно, так  как основное деление его делается паузой между предложениями 2 и 3. Делать еще одну паузу внутри вставочного изъяснительного предложения 2 неправильно. А без паузы нет интонационного тире.

Comment: Jasmin, мне кажется, запятая и тире как единый знак здесь не очень подойдёт, т.к. присоединительная конструкция "особенно если..." относится скорее к предшествующему придаточному, нежели к главному предложению. "Не гарант компетентности, особенно если...", а не "Он понимает, особенно если...".

Comment: А мне как раз хотелось отнести присоединительное предложение не к придаточному, а ко всему СПП. Сначала идет первая часть (СПП) как законченная мысль, а потом уже дополнительное сообщение. Сравнить:  Опыт далеко не гарант компетентности — особенно если это опыт выполнения одних и тех же механических обязанностей.

Comment: @– Jasmin, но ведь у нас придаточное выступает в качестве присоединительной конструкции. По правилам запятая и тире в таких конструкциях не ставится.

Comment: Тире/запятая и тире в СПП  являются неосновными знаками, а запятая - основным знаком. Пример: 1) Да, в принципе возможно ― особенно если фальсифицировано только содержание акта... [А. А. Зализняк. Лингвистика по А. Т. Фоменко // «Вопросы языкознания», 2000]  2)Иначе бывает, когда появляется вещь, сделанная только для того, чтобы причинять боль, ― особенно если она сделана искусно. [Александр Григоренко. Ильгет. Три имени судьбы // Урал, 2013]  3) Вот скобки: Лучшая альтернатива ― Россия (особенно если учесть, что ближневосточные армии имеют опыт обращения с нашим оружием).

Comment: Наречие "особенно"  выполняет роль присоединительного союза, и обычно ставится запятая, но в некоторых случаях автор может усилить присоединительный характер, используя паузу и тире.

Comment: Если ставить запятую и тире, то каждый знак — на своём основании, в зависимости от того, относится ли присоединительная конструкция к придаточному или ко всему СПП. Запятая и тире как единый знак выполняет немного другие функции (после ряда однородных придаточных и при повторении слова из первой части).

Comment: @Jasmin Давайте подведём итог. Я правильно понял, что если присоединительная конструкция по смыслу относится к предшествующему придаточному, а не ко всему СПП, то в моём случае знаки препинания расставлены правильно?

Comment: Извините, отвечу чуть позже (вечером), сейчас нет времени.

Comment: В классических правилах в СПП  перед "особенное если" ставится запятая, но Вы можете поставить тире как авторский знак, обозначив увеличенную паузу. Такое решение можно встретить у очень авторитетных авторов. Я уже приводила пример Зализняка, а вот еще Гончаров И.А.: Эти роли...самые трудные, почти бесколоритные, так сказать, отрицательные роли ― особенно если они лишены драматического пафоса..."

Answer (score 0):

В роли присоединительной конструкции может выступать и придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения:

Ср.**: Необходимы были всякие меры предосторожности, особенно если приходилось идти ночью; В некоторых условиях обстановки, и в частности когда войска на отдыхе, кухни располагаются на грунте.**

[См.: Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)