# Запятая перед союзом "благодаря тому, что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение

*Уже через несколько минут это маленькое хрупкое лицо казалось прелестным, именно благодаря тому, что оно было таким неправильным* (Кар.).

Почему перед "именно" стоит запятая, ведь либо оборот обособляется вместе со сложным союзом, либо первая часть входит в главную часть как соотносительное слово, а вторая выступает в роли союза, и в этих случаях запятая ставится только перед второй частью сочетания (т. е. перед союзами что, чтобы, как). При этом для за союза "благодаря тому, что" характерен второй вариант. Тем более ещё стоит усилительная частица.

Answer (score 2):

**Уже через несколько минут это маленькое хрупкое лицо казалось прелестным, именно благодаря тому, что оно было таким неправильным (Кар.).**

Это предложение взято из правил Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Но я думаю, что это неудачный пример, так как пунктуация здесь а**вторского характера и связана с присоединительным значением** придаточного и наличием паузы. Такие варианты у Розенталя не нормируются.

Автор текста — Анна  Караваева (типичный представитель социалистического реализма в литературе), она получила  Сталинскую премию третьей степени (1951) — за трилогию «Родина». Поэтому пунктуация здесь дореформенная.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

1) **Классический пример соответствует правилам**:

Не контузило меня **именно благодаря тому, что** снаряд упал перелетом...[В. Н. Гельфанд. Дневники 1941-1943 гг. (1941-1943)]

2) **Авторская пунктуация** (присоединение обозначено тире или запятой), тексты не соответствуют современным правилам:

Ты видишь сам, какое огромное впечатление произвело твое выступление против Мезенцова на площади, ― **именно благодаря тому, что** тебя до сих пор не могут найти. [Н. А. Морозов. Повести моей жизни/ «Земля и воля» (1913)]

Даже корреспонденты «Московских ведомостей» ― и те, мне кажется, кружат в трех соснах, **именно благодаря тому, что** помело, которое они употребляют, и помои, в которые макают это помело, все-таки преобразуют собой перо и чернила. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Круглый год (1879-1880)]

Comment: Кстати, у меня всегда возникает вопрос: присоединительная конструкция, в случае если предложение сложноподчинённое, может относиться к придаточному или она всегда относится ко всему предложению? Присоединительные члены, например, обычно присоединяются к определённому члену в предложении.

Comment: Присоединительная конструкция может быть любой, например у Розенталя: Он отказался принять вину на себя — с какой стати? http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Comment: Я имею в виду, присоединительное предложение может относиться к придаточному? Дело в том, что, когда такое присоединение обозначено знаком тире, появляется трудность: нужно ли ставить перед этим тире запятую или нет, как в моём вопросе https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436659/Правомерность-постановки-тире.

Comment: Здесь "именно" присоединительный союз, отнесенный к подчинительному союзу. Обычно перед союзом  "именно" ставится только запятая (этого достаточно), но может быть авторское тире (вместо запятой). Если стоит запятая и тире - то это сочетание знаков, запятая относится к предыдущему обороту.

Comment: Ещё раз задам вопрос по-другому: присоединительная конструкция (оборот, предложение) может относиться к придаточному предложению или к обособленному обороту, а не к главному предложению и при этом присоединяться при помощи тире? Я сейчас не про случай с "именно благодаря тому, что"! Забудем про него.